# SMTP User Unknown

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail, hostname

I have a server from which I am trying to send myself an email.  I have a domain name, example.com.  The A record for example.com points to this server.  The MX record points elsewhere.  I have the email me@example.com.

When I try to send myself an email (using python smtplib), I get the following:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'me@example.com': (550, '5.1.1 <me@example.com>... User unknown')}
```

I can send emails to recipients with any other domain name just fine.  I can also send emails to usernames that correspond to users that exist on the server, and these emails end up in the appropriate /var/spool/mail file.  From this, it is obvious that the server believes it is the intended recipient of email sent to users of example.com.

I have already changed the hostname of the server to something other than example.com.  This did not solve the problem.

I am using sendmail.

How do I get the server to realize that it is not the mail server for example.com?

Comment: Which MTA are you running (e.g. qmail? sendmail? exim? postfix)?  I think you're right that the MTA thinks it is the MX for example.com.  But, how to configure it so that it is not (i.e. so that it relays mail for example.com instead or routing mail locally) will depend on which MTA it is that you are running.  For most, it involves editing a virtualdomains file, and/or an rcpthosts file.

Comment: @mti2935 using sendmail.  Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the hostname to something other than `example.com`.  Then:

If using sendmail:

```
apt-get install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig
```

If using postfix:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```